# After doing a migration to nx's latest (16.7.4) projects stopped being detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, monorepo, nrwl-nx, yarn-v2

After trying to migrate nx to the latest version via:

```
nx migrate latest
```

and running the migrations and yarn my projects in the monorepo stopped being detected by int:

```
nx show projects
```

Simply outputs blank.

The setup is:

- nx v16.7.4 (local)
- yarn 3.6.1
- node 16.19.1

And I use asdf on an M1 mac.

If I revert back to a previous version of nx (15.9.2) all work fine. I'm busting yarn and nx caches as well as deleting yarn.lock and/or removing node_modules without luck.

Any idea/suggestion on how we can trace this or how to fix it?

Comment: File a github issue / add details to the existing one [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/18730), ideally with a way of reproducing. If you have time bisect your way through nx versions to see which patch caused the issue - this is one of the fastest ways of getting the maintainers to address an issue

Comment: I did so thank you. Interestingly enough we have similar problems. Also 16.5 works fine for me but after that it starts not detecting the projects...i think I've tried everything..

Comment: Ideally if can you identify the minor patch too? 16.5.1-16.5.5, 16.6.0-beta.0-16.6.0-beta.8

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging on my env I could find the root of it.

TL;DR please look into your ignore files *both on your project directory but as well your home directory* and check if they contain either:

- *.json
- project.json
- package.json

If so then nx won't be finding your apps and libs as their `project.json` files will be ignored.

Basically on my specific case I had a `.ignore` file, on macOS, that I really don't know what tool created it (intelliJ, solargraph, ?) hence my files started being ignored after 16.6.0.

After removing those ignore entries it all started working properly.